# How do i open a program in a separate terminal from c++ code?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gnome-terminal

I want to do following tasks programmatically.

1. In C++, open a terminal (system("gnome-terminal");)
2. In C++,
   run a program located at some place (./myprogram)

Here is my code

```
strcpy(args, "gnome-terminal");
strcpy(args, "-e 'sh ./spout");
strcat(args, "' ");
system(args);
```

But It gives following error on runtime.

```
sh: 0: Illegal option -
```

Comment: The second `strcpy` overwrites the first one. Why aren't you using `std::string?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the fact that there might be more elegant solutions than invoking a terminal via C++ to execute a programm you could go with one of these:

**std::string**

The most obvious solution is to use `std::string` which provides the overloaded operator `+` to concat strings.

```
#include <string>

std::string args = "gnome-terminal ";
args += "-e 'sh ./spout";
args += "' ";
```

**std::stringstream**

`std::stringstream` is another option:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::stringstream ss;
ss << "gnome-terminal "; 
ss << "-e 'sh ./spout";
ss << "' ";
std::string args = ss.str();
```

**strcat()**

If you want to use C strings you can use something like this. Note that I do not recommend this.

```
#include <cstring>

strcpy(args, "gnome-terminal");
strcat(args, "-e 'sh ./spout");
strcat(args,  "' ");
```

Please note, that the second version needs a closer look at the allocated memory for `args`. See [strcat()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat) for further information.