# What is the simplest way to run an .exe external program with parameters Please, I need a simple code example

Tags: c++

Please, I need a simple code example showing how to run an `.exe` program with parameters from inside my C++ program.

Something like:

```
myExternal program
```

```
int main (int a , int b)
{
    int c = a+b;
    return c;
}
```

My Caller program looks like this:

```
int Caller_main ()
{
    execute( myExternalprogram.exe, (with parameters 5 and 6!));
    get (the result!);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i open a program in a separate terminal from c++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43342796/how-do-i-open-a-program-in-a-separate-terminal-from-c-code)

Comment: And this is how to use `argc` and `argv`: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/01/c-argc-argv/

Comment: This is a duplicate to this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-do-i-execute-a-command-and-get-the-output-of-the-command-within-c-using-po#478960](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-do-i-execute-a-command-and-get-the-output-of-the-command-within-c-using-po#478960)

Comment: Note: while it's not impossible, it is unusual for main to accept a pair of `int`s. Typically `main` accepts either nothing or a count and an array of strings of size specified by the count.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [system()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system)? `std::system("command")`. Something like:

```
std::string myCmd = "myExternalprogram.exe abc 123"; // Obviously append the parameters
std::system(myCmd.c_str());
```

Comment: This doesn't show how to read the output of the spawned program, though.